# Too long line in a doctest

Tags: python-3.x, doctest, pylama

I'm writing, in Python, a class that emulates a numeric types. I'd like to have some numerous doctests, as well as to have no pycodestyle warning from pylava.

Here is my difficulty.

For the following doctest

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
            ...
        TypeError: Only RiemannSphere, integers or floats can be added to a RiemannSphere
```

I've got a warning from pylava, because my line `TypeError: ...`is too long.

Is someone knows how to cut it into two lines even if it is in a doctest?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I've just found out a nice solution, using ELLIPSIS:

The initial doctest was:

```
        >>> 1j / z1
        Traceback (most recent call last):
            ...
        TypeError: Only RiemannSphere, integers or floats can be added to a RiemannSphere
```

Using the [# doctest: +ELLIPSIS directive](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#doctest.ELLIPSIS), this can be written shortly:

```
        >>> 1j / z1
        ... # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
        Traceback (most recent call last):
            ...
        TypeError: Only a RiemannSphere, ... divided by a RiemannSphere number
```

Consequently, it's now easy to change the message in the Traceback so that pylava does not give warning.